# How can I distribute WP8 app to testers?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have created some WP8 app. I have .xap file.
How can I send it to testers so they could test the app on their devices?

Comment: Am I asking too global question, or this question is not for StackOverflow?
Any advice is appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: No, Windows Phone community is too small... Just compare count of questions between Android or iOS and WP. I do not understand, why guys from Micrsoft are not answering here, they could make platform more popular for developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a different way. If their devices are developer unlocked, they can deploy the .xap file directly to their devices by using the "Application deployment" tool (installed along with the SDK). You can unlock up to three devices on one DevCenter Account using "Windows Phone Developer Registration" tool (also installed with the SDK).

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to send out a "Beta" app via email under the Windows Phone Dashboard, found at dev.windowsphone.com.

You have to be setup for a developer account and pay the fee of $99. Hope this helps.

Comment: MSDN documentation on this subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Did all the things you said.
After filling all the text boxes for app description, I clicked on Beta, and after that on Submit.

Now I get "STATUS: IN SIGNING STAGE". Of course, still didn't get any notification about app on my test device.
Am I doing something wrong, or I need to wait for some time until this "SINGING STAGE" pass? Will it then notify my test device about build?

Comment: Slavisa, yes, Microsoft must "sign off" on your application.  This can take up to 7 days I believe.  Typically, I have seen my apps get published 3-5 days after it goes into the signing stage.  Once they are done checking it out, it will either be ready to go, or they will ask for you to make changes.

Comment: @AnthWard Does that mean that each time I want to send a build to testers, I have to wait for a week until they get it?! There must be a better/quicker way to distribute it to test devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only way I know of, unless you physically have their device and can launch the app on it directly (i.e., borrow their device, plug it into your machine via USB cable, click debug > device. Microsoft is strict on deploying apps to devices without them being signed first, I'm pretty sure Apple is the same way.

Comment: That is actually terrible... 
Apple use the functionality of TestFlight, and the process is much, much quicker. Test devices get a build in a couple of minutes. I was hoping that WP have the similar thing. And they will have to make some quick distribution mechanism, because this is just unacceptable.
Anyway, thank you for your time and useful answers. I've learned something today. :)

Comment: That's a shame about WP.  Maybe they will take a page out of the Apple book someday and do what you mentioned ;).  Good luck slavisa.

Answer (score 0):

There is also windows phone power tools that supports windows 7 and is lightweight and don't need visual studio installed:

http://wptools.codeplex.com/releases/view/97029